# calling a number using my app using phoneCallURL swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to call 999 from my app after clicking ISAF button, here is my code:

```
@IBAction func isaf(_ sender: UIButton) {

  func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
        if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(999)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL as URL)) {
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL);

                callNumber(phoneNumber: "999")
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

but I did not work, what should I change? I did not add any thing in the ViewController` but the above code, if there any thing else please tell.

Thanks

Comment: Why yo call same function again and again? create recursive cycle which never end look your code in canOpenURL

Comment: @chiragshah would you please write it like a full answer below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Calling is not supported by Simulator.**

**`You have to test it on real iphone device.`**

Please update your code like below:

```
@IBAction func isaf(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(999)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL as URL)) {
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL);
        }
    }       
}
```

There in no need to write it like "(999)" as 999 is not a variable it is a simple Number.:

Comment: I did but it still the same.

Comment: @Mzochi Are you testing it on device not in simulator?

Comment: on Iphone 5s  simulator

Comment: @Mzochi it will not work in simulator :) try it on device.